# Using Lat Long from model data in view to populate google map coordinates

Tags: google-maps, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a small app that retrieves data from a database and displays information. It is all vehicle information and two of the fields are Latitude and Longitude.

I am trying to get a map to show up when the user clicks "Details" but I cannot figure out how to get the model data into the function so that it shows.

What I have tried.

```
//Setting a hidden input equal to the value
<input type='hidden' id='test-lat' value='@Html.Display(model => model.Lat)' />

//Then starting the script
<script>
       var a = $('#test-lat').val();
       var map;
       function initMap() {
           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
               center: {lat: a, lng: 41},
               zoom: 8
           });
       }
</script>
```

This just gives me a gray box

Comment: You should not really need the hidden input - it could be just `center: { lat: '@Model.Lat', lng: '@Model.Lon' },` What does `console.log(a);` output? Is it the expected value?

Comment: Wow....I didn't even think of that, I need to get some sleep :)

If you want to make that into an answer I'll gladly accept. I was getting the same value but the maps function just wasn't accepting it in that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use hidden-control, you can directly implement model value as parameters.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        initialize();
    });
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng('@Model.Lat', '@Model.Lng'),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        // create a marker
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng('@Model.Lat', '@Model.Lng');
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Vehicle Place'
        });
    }
</script>
```